# Why isn't my image responsive to sizing but everything else is?

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzsZs.jpg

I am doing a project for my IT Course. I am having trouble getting the website  to be responsive.
My logo and my navbar both seem to be responsive however, the image of the house does not seem to be responsive. (The link above is 90% zoom)

I have tried editing the size of the width and height but as I am very new to it I am struggling to solve the issue.

I would like the top image to be responsive. How do I do this?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
 margin: 0px;
}
/*This is the container css*/
.container {
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-right: 200px;
 margin-top: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.logo h1 {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 color: #232323;
 font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
}

.navbar {
 float: right;
 top: 0;
 padding: 10px;
}

.navbar ul a:hover {
 padding: 5px; 
 margin: 0;
 background-color: lightblue;
}

.navbar li {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px;
 color: black;
 font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
}

/*This is the top image css*/
#top-img {
 background-image: url("images/top-img.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 min-width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-bottom: solid #3E3E3E 3px;
}

/*This is the @media i am trying to make the top image responsive*/
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    #top-img {
        max-width: 50em;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    #top-img {
        max-width: 70em;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Plantscape</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="top-img">
 <div class="container">
 <header>
  <div class="logo">
   <h1>Plantscape</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
   <ul>
    <a href="portfolio.html"><li>Folio</li></a>
    <a href="services.html"><li>Services</li></a>
    <a href="about.html"><li>About Us</li></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the image as a background as opposed to an HTML element. You've told your `#top-img` element to be responsive, but you haven't told the background to be responsive. Try adding the following declaration to your CSS:

```
 #top-img {
     ...
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much, I will keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `background-size:cover` for your `top-img` class to fit full-width of the page.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
}


/*This is the container css*/

.container {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #232323;
    font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
}

.navbar {
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.navbar ul a:hover {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
}


/*This is the top image css*/

#top-img {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: solid #3E3E3E 3px;
}


/*This is the @media i am trying to make the top image responsive*/

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    #top-img {
        max-width: 50em;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    #top-img {
        max-width: 70em;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="top-img">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Plantscape</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <a href="portfolio.html">
                        <li>Folio</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="services.html">
                        <li>Services</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="about.html">
                        <li>About Us</li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="contact.html">
                        <li>Contact Us</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code and found that your are using a house image as a background image, so my suggestion is kindly use css property background-size:cove for your class name #top-img and kindly remove height when you make mobile responsive layout, that time mention height:auto.

```
suggested css{

#top-img {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   background-image: url("images/top-img.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: solid #3E3E3E 3px;
    background-size:cove;
}
```